# Is there a simple explanation why $E=mc²$ is double the maximum kinetic energy?

Tags: special-relativity, kinematics, mass-energy

Since kinetic energy is $\frac 12 mv^2$, and the maximum speed is the speed of light $c$, how come total energy is double the maximum kinetic energy?

Comment: In relativity, kinetic energy is _not_ $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ anymore. That formula is only valid for low velocities.

Comment: Also there is no maximum kinetic energy. It can grow indefinitely. Only speed has a maximum

Answer (score 7):

To see the relation between the two quantities, it's most straightforward to derive the nonrelativistic kinetic energy from the relativistic total energy.

The total energy of a body with mass $m$ moving with velocity $v$ is given by:

$$E(v)=\frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$

This means that the kinetic energy $K$ is equal to the difference of the total energy and the energy at rest:

$$K(v)=E(v)-E(0)=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}-1\right)$$

If we take the Taylor expansion of $K(v)$ about $v=0$, we get:

$$K(v)=K(0)+K'(0)v+\frac{1}{2}K''(0)v^2+...$$

Computing the terms:

$$K(0)=E(0)-E(0)=0$$

$$K'(v)=mc^2\frac{v}{c^2\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{3/2}}\implies K'(0)=0$$

$$K''(v)=mc^2\left(\frac{1}{c^2\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{3v^2}{c^4\left(1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}\right)^{5/2}}\right)\implies K''(0)=m$$

And substituting:

$$K(v)=0+0v+\frac{1}{2}mv^2+...=\frac{1}{2}mv^2+...$$

For small velocities (i.e. in the non-relativistic regime), terms that are higher-order in $v$ (e.g. terms multiplied by $v^3$, $v^4$, etc.) are very small and can be neglected. This is why the non-relativistic kinetic energy is $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$.

So, to summarize, $mc^2$ is related to $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$ because:

- The second derivative of kinetic energy at small velocities is $m$.
- The quadratic term in any Taylor expansion has a coefficient of $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the kinetic energy formula was already a simplification.